# Dont "animate" the X axis. Have the value on graph while the lines animate

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code.

```
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
df = xls_file.parse('fileTab')

chart = {'Date': df['Date'],
        'Total': df['Total']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(chart, columns = ['Date', 'Total'])
title = 'Total'
x = np.array(df.index)
y = np.array(df['Total'])
yData = pd.DataFrame(y,x)
yData.columns = {title}


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
# plt.xlim(df['Date'][0])
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=.20)
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=.20)
plt.ylim(np.min(yData)[0], np.max(yData)[0])
plt.xlabel('Yr',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel(title,fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_xticks(range(43))
ax.set_xticklabels(df['Date'])

def formatY(x, pos):
    s = '%d' % x
    groups = []
    while s and s[-1].isdigit():
        groups.append(s[-3:])
        s = s[:-3]
    return s + ','.join(reversed(groups))

def animate(i):
    data = yData.iloc[:int(i+1)] #select data range
    p = sns.lineplot(x=data.index, y=data[title], color="r")
    p.tick_params(labelsize=7)
    plt.setp(p.lines,linewidth=2)

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 50, repeat=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FuncFormatter(formatY))
plt.show()
```

I am trying to only animate the line itself. However, currently, the xAxis animates with the line. Each index on the X axis shows up during each interval. How can I have the xAxis show when the graph loads?

Comment: `plt.xlim(0, 44)` should fix the x limits (in the same way you have done for the y limits)

Comment: @tmdavison knew i missed something stupid. thanks so much.